# temporal io server not accessible for application deployed using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

I have a Golang application deployed by Jenkins in **server1**.domain.com that connects to a temporal-server that runs on **server2**.domain.com.

Next is how the Makefile looks.

```
http_proxy=http://myproxy.domain.com:80
https_proxy=http://myproxy.domain.com:80
no_proxy=".domain.com,127.0.0.0/8,localhost"

TEMPORAL_SERVER=server2.domain.com:11111

....

run:
  ./App $(TEMPORAL_SERVER)
```

The application always fails in creating the client because it doesn't reach the server where the temporal-server is running.

This is a problem only when using Jenkins, *if I go to the directory where Jenkins deployed the code and do "**make run**" the application creates the temporal client with no issues.*

I need to understand what is happening here, losing my hair over this... thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone finds this helpful.

RCA was that the Jenkins master script was also declaring different no_proxy vars that were overriding those in the makefile.